# iOS view controllers with pinch zoom, pan, and swipe between pages

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out the right way to configure a UIViewController to behave similarly to the photo gallery view in the iOS camera app. In other words, you can pinch zoom the photos, pan around them, but when you get to the edge of the photo, it pages to the next image. It seems like you could hypothetically achieve this with a set of UIScrollViews inside of a UIPageViewController, if you could somehow distinguish between the intention to pan the photo and the intention to switch pages. But in practice it seems that the UIPageViewController's gesture recognizer supercedes all, so any swipe switches pages instead of panning.

I could add my own gesture recognizers to do this, but it seems like there's a lot of behavior I'd need to replicate, so I'm hoping there's some combination of existing stuff I can use to get reasonably close.

Comment: You can achieve it with UICollectionView and UIScrollView as u have mentioned. No need to add any custom gesture recognizer. You can add a scrollView to Cell and make the CollectionViewCell cover the whole collectionView. When user taps on swipes its the cell's scrollView that takes the touches there u can scale of UIScrollView to make the zoom effect. When user swipes to extreme of the sides with image zoomed or swipes when Image is not zoomed collectionView will take care of swiping to next cell no need to do anything manually

Comment: You can also use nested scrollviews. A parent scrollview for scrolling photos and individual scrollviews for each photo. Refer this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229940/triple-nested-uiscrollview-paging-issue/9229640#9229640